# Conflicting Intent Filters in Manifest

Tags: android, intentfilter

For our splash activity, we have an intent-filter set for deep linking.  Here it is:

```
<activity
    android:name=".activity.SplashActivity"
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|locale"
    android:label="${applicationLabel}"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar.Translucent">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

        <data
            android:host="@string/tve_host"
            android:scheme="@string/market_scheme" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Now, we have a live tv activity that is looking for the same scheme and same host but a specific path.  Here it is:

```
<activity
            android:name=".activity.TveActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|locale"
            android:parentActivityName=".activity.HomeActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:path="/live"
                    android:host="@string/tve_host"
                    android:scheme="@string/market_scheme" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

When clicking a link with that path, it gives a choice between both activities.

Is there any way to prevent this other than specifically listing all other paths in the intent-filters for the splash activity?

Answer (score 0):

Accordingly to the [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html), no, there's no such way. You have to list all other paths in the intent-filter for the splash activity.

Comment: nuts.  that's what I was afraid of

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified the path on the original intent, thus it matches anything.

If you add

```
android:path="/"
```

it will match an empty path only and will consider this being different than `/live`.